# create clickable overlay and have click go through to button also

Tags: button, onclick, overlay

I have a button that is clickable. I want to dynamically put an overlay over it that is also clickable. When the overlay is on top and clicked I want the overlay onclick to be triggered, and the button onclick to be triggered.

Right now if I put the overlay on top with an onclick handler the click does not go through to the button underneath.
If I use pointerEvents="none" on the overlay then the click goes through but does not trigger the overlay onclick.

How can I get both onclicks to trigger when the overlay is on top?

```
<html><body>

   <input type=button value=clickme style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:25px;z-index:-1" onclick="alert('button')" >
    </body></html>

    <script>


    function createDiv(){
        alert("creating div");
        divTag = document.createElement("div"); 
        divTag.id="overlay";
        document.body.appendChild(divTag); 
        divTag.setAttribute("onclick","alert('overlay')");
         divTag.style.backgroundColor="rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5)";
         divTag.style.top="0px";
         divTag.style.left="0px";
         divTag.style.width="100px";
         divTag.style.height="100px";
         divTag.style.zIndex=100;
         //divTag.style.pointerEvents="none";
         //divTag.style.pointerEvents="auto";

    }
    setTimeout(createDiv,2000);
    </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q6Levpds/

Answer (score -1):

It's simple, don't touch the `z-index` of button, and set overlay `z-index` to -1

```
JS:

function createDiv(){
    alert("creating div");
   divTag = document.createElement("div"); 
   divTag.id="overlay";
     document.body.appendChild(divTag); 
     divTag.setAttribute("onclick","alert('overlay')");
     divTag.style.backgroundColor="rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5)";
     divTag.style.top="0px";
     divTag.style.left="0px";
     divTag.style.width="100px";
     divTag.style.height="100px";
     divTag.style.zIndex=-1;
     //divTag.style.pointerEvents="none";
     //divTag.style.pointerEvents="auto";

}
setTimeout(createDiv,2000);
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<input type=button value="clickme" style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:25px" onclick="alert('button')" />
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q6Levpds/1/

Comment: In your changed example at least on firefox the overlay is behind the button and just the button click is triggered. I was trying to get the overlay click to trigger also.

Comment: @techdog you want to activate overlay click when button is clicked